# Enreco Video Rotation in Asp.Net Virtual Machine is not completing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ffmpeg, virtual-machine

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Api in which I need to concatenate some video clips and rotate them. I could achieve the same when I tried in my local system. When I deployed the same project to an Azure Virtual Machine I am not getting response. I am pretty sure that there isn't any issue till video concatenation because I could see the concatenated video in the expected folder. Here is the code snippet.

```
 var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
            NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings set = new NReco.VideoConverter.ConcatSettings();
            ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(_fileNames[0], imageRootPath + tobename + ".jpg");
  if (_fileNames.Count() > 1)
            {
                ffMpeg.ConcatMedia(_fileNames, videoRootPath + tobename + "_r.mp4", NReco.VideoConverter.Format.mp4, set);

                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\bin\\");
                System.Diagnostics.Process ffmpeg = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = path + "\\" + "ffmpeg.exe";
                ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + videoRootPath + tobename + "_r.mp4" + " -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 " + videoRootPath + tobename + ".mp4";
                ffmpeg.Start();
                ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
            }
```

ffmpeg.ConcateMedia is working fine. I can't figure out why the External process that I have invoked does not complete. The same piece is working fine in my local Visual Studio.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Nreco VideoConvertor for joinging videos and  external process to rotate the video.

You can always use Invoke method to write the custom commandline. something like this

```
ffMpeg.Invoke("-i " + videoRootPath + tobename + "_r.mp4" + " -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 " + videoRootPath + tobename + ".mp4");
```

Hope this Helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your path ends with a slash, and when adding the paths together you also add a slash.

Use `Path.Combine`:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\bin");

ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ffmpeg.exe");
```

Comment: Thank You for the quick response. I will get back to you after checking